# Permanently open a COM port in MatLab

Tags: matlab, serial-port, matlab-guide

So in my MatLab program I open a COM port to broadcast a pulse using the following:

```
x = serial('COM10','Baudrate',9600);
```

However the COM port closes after the pulse has been sent. Since I'm going to be sending lots of pulses throughout the execution of the program I want to keep the COM port permanently open so that I don't have to keep reopening it.

I'm unsure how to do this, it was suggested to me that I put the com port variable into a handle in MatLab to keep it permanently open but I'm not sure how to do this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be open until you close it with fclose:

```
% Creat serial object
x = serial('COM10','Baudrate',9600);
% Open serial port
fopen(x);
% Write to serial port
fprintf(x,'ABC');'
fprintf(x,'DEF');'
% ... 

% Close the serial port
fclose(x);
```